# Python: "Undefined symbol" encountered in CentOS Linux 7 16.04

Tags: linux, python-2.7, importerror

I'm using brian 1.4.3 (I realize that brain2 is currently supported and brian is not, but I am trying to extend some old brian code), and, when attempting to run the program on my university's computing cluster (CentOS Linux 7) and my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, I get the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "spiking_MNIST.py", line 564, in <module>
    b.run(single_example_time)
  File "/home/djsaunde/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/brian/network.py", line 938, in run
    report=report, report_period=report_period)
  File "/home/djsaunde/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/brian/network.py", line 574, in run
    self.update()
  File "/home/djsaunde/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/brian/network.py", line 518, in update
    f()
  File "/home/djsaunde/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/brian/neurongroup.py", line 498, in update
    spikes = self._threshold(self) # get spikes
  File "/home/djsaunde/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/brian/threshold.py", line 183, in __call__
    extra_compile_args=self._extra_compile_args)
  File "/home/djsaunde/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/inline_tools.py", line 366, in inline
    **kw)
  File "/home/djsaunde/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/inline_tools.py", line 502, in compile_function
    exec('import ' + module_name)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/djsaunde/.cache/scipy/python27_compiled/sc_d99244cd82bb18764cebf838c5d78a223.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE9_M_createERmm
```

Keep in mind, the code works perfectly find on my laptop (previously running Ubuntu 14.04, but recently upgraded to 16.04, but it still works). Any insight would be greatly appreciated.